# android add listener for sending message

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app. I have a `MainFragment` that controls `childfragment`. In `childfragment`,when there is a button click, I need to send a text message. I need to add a listener for this.

In `MainFragment`, I need to listen to this event and send it to `MainActivity` for sending a message.

How do I implement a listener and remove it when it is not needed

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by defining interfaces in your fragments, for example 
you can listen to the event in your MainFragment like that:

```
    // in your child fragment define an interface
interface MyOnClickListener {
    void onClick();
}

MyOnClickListener myClickListener;
public void setMyCustomClickListener(MyOnClickListener myClickListener){
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

// and on button click
@Override
void onClick(View v){
    myClickListener.onClick()
}



// In your MainFragment
myChildFragment.setMyCustomClickListener(new MyOnClickListener {
    @Override
    onClick(){
        //do your staff yere
    }
})
```

also this is same tactic for your MainActivity

Comment: Thank you :) But I need to send some text message argument from child fragment to main fragment. How do I do this?